# Unable to execute tests through Runnable jar using CLI Commands

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, cucumber, build.gradle

I am working on test automation using the below technologies like java,selenium,cucumber & Gradle.

Though Iam able to create a jar successfully but still while executing with Cli Commands it throws an exception saying, "**Failed to parse '729452**'".

I am not sure what is the issue for which it is not working.

Please find my build.gradle file

```
enter code here
/*
 * This file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * User Manual available at https://docs.gradle.org/6.3/userguide/java_library_plugin.html



plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java'       
    id 'java-library'
    id "ua.eshepelyuk.ManifestClasspath" version "1.0.0"
    
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java-library-distribution'

compileJava {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}

        
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    //maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

    
ext {
         
         
         //Selenium Api
         seleniumServerversion = '4.0.0-alpha-2'
         seleniumVersion = '4.1.1'
         seleniumHtmlUnitDriverVersion = '2.52.0'
         
         //WebDriverManager
         webdriverManagerVersion = '5.2.0'
         
        //Cucumber
         cucumberVersion = '7.2.3'  
          
         //Log4j
         Log4jVersion = '1.2.17'
         
         //slf4j-api
         slf4jVersion = '1.7.30'
                  
         
         //commons-configuration
         commonsConfigurationVersion = '1.10'
         
      
        //Commons
          commonsCodecVersion = '1.6'
          commonsLoggingVersion = '1.1.3'
        
        //Dom4j
          dom4jVersion = '2.1.3'
        
          
        //ExtentReport    
          extentreportVersion = '5.0.3'

    }

dependencies {

     

    //--------------------------------------courgette Dependency ----------------------------------------------------   
        //Courgette Plugin for parallel Testing
        //compile 'io.github.prashant-ramcharan:courgette-jvm:6.4.2'
        
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.prashant-ramcharan/courgette-jvm
        implementation group: 'io.github.prashant-ramcharan', name: 'courgette-jvm', version: '6.5.0'
        //compile 'io.github.prashant-ramcharan:webdriver-binary-downloader:1.3.0'
        
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.prashant-ramcharan/webdriver-binary-downloader
       // implementation group: 'io.github.prashant-ramcharan', name: 'webdriver-binary-downloader', version: '1.3.0'           
        
        
    //-----------------------------------Selenium Apis---------------------------------------------------------------
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-server
        implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version: seleniumServerversion
        implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: seleniumVersion
        implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-htmlunit-driver', version: seleniumHtmlUnitDriverVersion
        implementation 'com.paulhammant:ngwebdriver:1.1.4'  
    
    //--------------------------------------Webdriver manager-------------------------------------------------------
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager
        implementation group: 'io.github.bonigarcia', name: 'webdrivermanager', version: webdriverManagerVersion


    //-----------------------------------------Cucumber------------------------------------------------------------ 
    
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core
        implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-core', version: cucumberVersion
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java
        implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java', version: cucumberVersion
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java8
        //implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-java8', version: cucumberVersion
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit
       // testImplementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: cucumberVersion
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng
        implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-testng', version: cucumberVersion         
        
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm-deps
        compileOnly group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-jvm-deps', version: '1.0.6'           
        
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin
        //implementation group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'gherkin', version: gherkinVersion
              
        
    //---------------------------------------TestNg--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //testImplementation "org.testng:testng:${testngVersion}"
        //testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.13.1'
        implementation group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: testngVersion
        
   //-------------------------------------Log4j Logs------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        implementation "log4j:log4j:${Log4jVersion}"  //Do not change from implementation to testImplementation otherwise  PropertyConfigurator and Logger will throw errors
    
        implementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: slf4jVersion
        testImplementation group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: slf4jVersion   
  
   //-------------------------------------commons-configuration-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        implementation group: 'commons-configuration', name: 'commons-configuration', version: commonsConfigurationVersion
    
    
   //-------------------------------------Json Schema validator--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       //Json Schema validator  
         implementation group: 'io.rest-assured', name: 'json-schema-validator', version: jsonSchemaValidatorVersion

    //-----------------------------------------Commons-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Commons Codec
            implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: commonsCodecVersion
        //Commons Logging
            implementation group: 'commons-logging', name: 'commons-logging', version: commonsLoggingVersion


    //-----------------------------------------Dom4j-------------------------------------------------------------------------
        implementation group: 'org.dom4j', name: 'dom4j', version: dom4jVersion         
    

   //---------------------------------------AspectJweaver--------------------------------------------------------
        implementation group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjweaver', version: aspectJWeaverVersion   
        
                
    //--------extentreports------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        implementation "com.aventstack:extentreports:$extentreportVersion"
    
         

}

 sourceSets {
                   main {
                               java   {
                                        srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src/test/java']
                                      }
                                 
                            resources {
                                        srcDirs = ['src/main/resources','src/test/resources']
                                      }
                        
                        }
                }
                
                
                
         distZip.shouldRunAfter(build)

     jar {
            // Keep jar clean:
            exclude 'META-INF/*.SF', 'META-INF/*.DSA', 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.MF'
           
            from sourceSets.main.output   
            manifest {
                           attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.rediff.test.runners.RediffMain',
                           'Class-Path': configurations.runtimeClasspath.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
            }
            
        }  
                
                
    
tasks.withType(Test) {
systemProperties = System.getProperties()
systemProperties.remove("java.endorsed.dirs")
```

}

```
    /* TestNG Specific Tasks
----------------------------------------------------
*/
task runTest(type: Test, dependsOn: compileTestJava) {
    useTestNG()

    
    systemProperty "UserRole", project.findProperty("role") ?: ""
    systemProperty "environment", project.findProperty("env") ?: "QA"
    systemProperty "platform", project.findProperty("plt")  ?: "UI"
    systemProperty "browser", project.findProperty("browser")  ?: "CHROME"
    systemProperty "bsBrowser", project.findProperty("bsBrowser") ?: "CHROME"
    systemProperty "bsBrowserVersion", project.findProperty("bsBrowserVersion")
    systemProperty "bsDevice", project.findProperty("bsDevice")  ?: "Desktop"
    systemProperty "bsDesktopOS", project.findProperty("bsDesktopOS")  ?: "Windows"
    systemProperty "bsOSVersion", project.findProperty("bsOSVersion")  ?: "10"
    systemProperty "bsMobileOS", project.findProperty("bsMobileOS")  ?: "Android"
    systemProperty "cucumber.tags", project.findProperty("testTag")  ?: "@sanity"
    systemProperty "courgette.threads", project.findProperty("threads")  ?: "1"
    systemProperty "courgette.rerunFailedScenarios", project.findProperty("rerunfailed")  ?: "false"

    include 'src/main/java/*.class'
    include 'src/test/java/*.class'
    include 'src/main/resources/configfile/*.*'
    include 'src/test/resources/*.*'

    include '**/rediff/test/runners/Rediff_Runner.class' // pass the runner class path
    //include '**/suites/testng/ChromeTestSuite.class'
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}


    
static def getDate() {
    return new Date().format('ddMMMyyyy_HH_mm')
}


def archiveFileName(){

    if (project.findProperty("plt").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("browserstack")){
        return (project.findProperty("testTag").toString().replace(" ","").replace("or","_")+ "_"+
                project.findProperty("env").toString().toUpperCase()+"_"+
                project.findProperty("bsDevice").toString().toUpperCase()+"_"+
                getDate()).replace("@","").toUpperCase()
    }else{
        return (project.findProperty("testTag").toString().replace(" ","").replace("or","_")+ "_"+
                project.findProperty("env").toString()+"_"+
                getDate()).replace("@","").toUpperCase()
    }

}

task archiveReports(type: Zip) {
    archiveFileName = archiveFileName()+".zip"
    destinationDirectory = file("Archive")
    from "./Automation_Report"

}
    
runTest.finalizedBy 'archiveReports'
```

## My Main class details

```
enter code here
```

public class RediffMain {

```
public static void main( String args[])throws Throwable
{
    System.out.println(" Inside Main class Method ");
    System.out.println(" ========================= ");
    

    try {
    
        String [] argv = new String[]{
                  "-g" ,  "com.rediff.test.stepdefs",
                  "-g" ,  "com.initDriver",
                  "classpath:features",
                 
                  "-g" ,   "ConfigFile",
               
                "-t", "@rediff_Tc111","@729452",
                
                "-p" , "true",
                "-p" , "pretty",
                "-p",  "json:target/Rediff.json",
                
                      };
        
        
    io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(argv);
    //cucumber.api.cli.Main(arguments);
    
     
    }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Main method exception");
            System.out.println(" Exception : "+e.getMessage());
    }       
}
```

}

Please find the snapshot of Jar
[image]

[image]

Below is the issue while executing jar with CLI command

java -jar SampleMavenProj_2023.jar gradle runTest  -PtestTag="@UHC_TC210" -Penv=QA -Pbrowser=CHROMIUM -Pplt=UI -Pthreads=1

[image]

I see that main method is getting executed but not sure at what statement this exception is thrown.

Just for your information I am using **Java 8 , Cucumber 7.2.3 , Gradle 7.1**.

I sincerely request everyone to please look into this issue and provide your advice here.

I am really fed-up with all the trails, but nothing worked..

Answer (score 0):

I can't say if you are making your executable jar correctly. I'm not familiar with Gradle.

But I can see that what you execute is not correct.

Specifically:

```
 "-t", "@rediff_Tc111","@729452",
```

Should probably be

```
 "-t", "@rediff_Tc111 or @729452",
```

Or maybe

```
 "-t", "@rediff_Tc111 and @729452",
```

Depending if you want to include all scenarios with either one of the tags, or only scenarios that have both tags.

Also this looks like a mistake:

```
"-p" , "true"
```